# Set of linearly independent $n$-tuples in infinite dimensional Banach space is open

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

is the following result true?

> Let $X$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space, and
> $$U=\{(x_1, \cdots, x_n) \in X^n: \{x_1, \cdots, x_n\} \text{ is linearly independent}\}$$
> then $U$ is open in $X^n$ with the product topology.

I think it is true, at least if $X$ is separable because I've encountered this result being used in a paper I'm reading but I cannot prove it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\{x_1, x_2,  \ldots , x_n\}\subseteq X$ is linearly independent, one can use  Hahn Banach to produce  continuous linear functionals $f_1,
f_2,  \ldots , f_n$  such that $f_i(x_j)=\delta _{i, j}$.   Therefore the matrix-valued linear transformation
$$
  T:(u_1,u_2,\ldots ,u_n)\in X^n \mapsto  \big (f_i(u_j)\big )_{i, j}\in  M_{n}({\mathbb R})
  $$
sends the $n$-tuple $(x_1, x_2,  \ldots , x_n)$ to the identity matrix.  Since $T$ is continuous and $GL_n({\mathbb R})$ is open,
there is a neighborhood of
$$
  \mathbb x:= (x_1, x_2,  \ldots , x_n)
  $$
in $X^n$, such that every
$$
  \mathbb u := (u_1, u_2,  \ldots , u_n)
  $$
in that neighborhood is
sent to an invertible matrix via $T$.  This implies  that the columns of $T(\mathbb u)$ are linearly independent, and
this is easily seen to imply that $\{u_1, u_2,  \ldots , u_n\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that this is true, and I think it amounts to intersecting finitely many (at most $2^n$) open neighbourhoods of any point that remain in $U$.

Saying $x_k$ is linearly independent of $\{x_1,...,x_n\}\setminus \{x_k \}$, is to say that

$$ x_k\neq \sum_{j\neq k}a_j \cdot x_j \quad \text{for all} \quad \{ a_j \}_{j\neq k }\subseteq \mathbb{F} . $$

Then the finite linear space spanned by $\{ x_j \}_{j\neq k}$ can be separated from $x_k$, and we can find neighbourhoods $V'_n, V_f''\subseteq X$ for all $j\neq k$ such that
if $y_k\in V_k'$ and $y_j\in V_j''$, then

$$ y_k \neq \sum_{j\neq k}a_j \cdot y_j \quad \text{for all} \quad \{ a_j \}_{j\neq k}\subseteq \mathbb{F} .  $$

This condition corresponds to the neighbourhood

$$ W_k:= \prod_{j\neq k}V_j'' \times Vk'.  $$

We can construct such a neighbourhood $W_k$ for all $1\leq k \leq n$, and define

$$W:= \bigcap_{k=1}^n W_k. $$

If

$$ x_k\neq \sum_{j\neq k}a_j \cdot x_j \quad \text{for all} \quad \{ a_j \}_{j\neq k }\subseteq \mathbb{F}  $$

for all $1\leq k\leq n$, then $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is linearly independent. Hence, every element in $(y_1,...,y_n)\in W$ is linearly independent, and we found a neighbourhood $W\subseteq U$ of $(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I don't get some points. The sets $V_k'$ and $V_j''$ are neighbourhoods of $x_k$ and the other $x_j$ with $j \not = k$? If so, why is $W_k \subset U$ Shouldn't it be, at the end, that $W=\bigcap_{k=1}^n W_k$, and then $W$ is in fact contained in $U$?

Comment: And, I also don't get how to exactly obtain the $V_k'$ and $V_j''$ for $j \not = k$ from the separation, could you explain that part a little bit more, please?

Comment: @Eparoh To your first comment, I miswrote and you are correct. The separation follows from Hahn Banach's theorem for the subspaces $M=span(\{ x_1,...,x_n \} \setminus \{x_k\})$ and $span(\{x_k\})$ like Ruy stated. i.e., a continuous functional $\psi_k$ such that $\psi_k\vert_M=0$ and $\psi_k(x_k)=1$.

Comment: Thanks, now I get it!